# Minimum of a sum proof.

Tags: statistics, proof-verification, maxima-minima, median

**The problem I am working on is:**

> Let $ Y = \{{y_1,y_2,y_3,...y_n\}}$ and $c=median(Y)$. Prove that:  $$
> \text{min}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \lvert y_{i}-c\rvert\right]=c $$

**My question is:**

Is the $\text{min}\left[\right]$ function here, asking for the which $y_i$ the distance between $y_i$ and $c$, $\lvert y_{i}-c\rvert$ is the smallest? Or is it asking, for the literal minimum of the arugments its given, like $\text{min}\left[99,1,4,7,121\right]=1$?

**What I have tried so far:**

**1.** First I tried an example to get a feel for things:

Let $ Y = \{{1,2,3,4,5\}}$ and $c=3$. Then we have:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^5 \lvert y_{i}-3\rvert & = \lvert 1-3\rvert = 2 \\
 & = \lvert 1-3\rvert = 2 \\ 
 & = \lvert 2-3\rvert = 1 \\
 & = \lvert 3-3\rvert = 0 \\
 & = \lvert 4-3\rvert = 1 \\
 & = \lvert 5-3\rvert = 2 \\ 
 & = 2+1+0+1+2=6
\end{align}$$
So,

$$ \text{min}\left[\sum_{i=1}^5 \lvert y_{i}-3\rvert\right]=\text{min}\left[6\right]=6
$$

Since this would now be acounterexample to the statement I am supposed to prove, I must be having a misunderstanding?

**2.** If the $\text{min}\left[\right]$ function works the other way, I tried the following proof:

Proof:

Since the distance between a point and itself is $0$, $\left[c-c\right]=0$ and the fact that there can only be one median $c$ for a given set of $y$, clearly $\left[c-c\right] \lt \left[y_i-c\right]$ for all $y_i.$

Is this correct if thats the case?

Comment: linear algebra $\neq$ peanut butter

Comment: the summation is over all possible $y_i's$

Comment: Part of me wants to say that this statement may not be correct. If we have a sample where each $y_i$ is the same, then $c=y_i$ for all $i$, thus...

Comment: What is the variable in your formula which minimizes it? It seems that all values are fixed. A clarification is needed.

Comment: I suspect that you are being asked to show that the $c$ which minimise(s) $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \lvert y_{i}-c\rvert$ for given $\{y_i\}$ is (or includes) the median of the  $\{y_i\}$